# Variable cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an item list, diffrent for each i and j variable. My code is:

```
if (i == 0) { 
            if (j == 0) { 
                final CharSequence[] items = {"4:45", "5:00"}
            } else if (j == 1) { 
                final CharSequence[] items = {"4:43", "4:58"}
            } else if (j == 2) { 
                final CharSequence[] items = {"4:41", "4:56"}
            } else { 
                final CharSequence[] items = {"4:38", "4:53"}
}
```

...

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
               .setTitle("Hours")
               .setItems(items,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                      // getStation(i);
                   }
                })
               .show();
       }
```

I get an error in the line `.setItems(items,`:

```
items cannot be resolved
```

I think that the compiler thinks that the `CharSequence[] items` may not be initialised or something... 
How can I make this programme run?

Comment: Hint: when the compiler thinks it is not initialized, then he will tell you that it's not initialized. If it says "cannot be resolved", then it means that it can't find the variable in any applicable scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is variable scoping.

```
if (someCondition) {
   final int i = 666;
} else {
   final int i = 42;
}
int j = i + 1; // compile-time error
```

Here we have two local variables `i` who goes out of scope immediately after they're declared and initialized. If `j` needs the value of `i`, then `i` would have to be declared in a larger scope.

```
final int i;
if (someCondition) {
   i = 666;
} else {
   i = 42;
}
int j = i + 1; // compiles fine!
```

(It should be mentioned that this is exactly the kind of scenarios where the ternary operator excels, i.e.)

```
final int i = (someCondition) ? 666 : 42;
```

---

In your specific case, unfortunately the array initializer shorthand can only be used to initialize upon declaration. That is:

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3 }; // compiles fine!
int[] arr2;
arr2 = { 4, 5, 6 }; // doesn't compile!
```

You can pull out the declaration of `items` outside the `if` and write the verbose code for each case (see Joachim Sauer's answer), but a more concise code is to use array-of-arrays instead.

```
final CharSequence[][] allItems = {
   { "4:45", "5:00" },
   { "4:43", "4:58" },
   { "4:41", "4:56" },
   { "4:38", "4:53" }
};
final CharSequence[] items = allItems[j];
```

This technique works well in this case, but in the more general case you want to use a `Map` or something similar.

Note: It's not explicit in the original code, but this works if `j` can either be `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`. If you want the last option to apply when `j` is any value other than `0`, `1`, `2`, then you have to check for that and set it to `3` before this code.

Answer (score 7):

You actually have 4 `items` variables in your code, each one with a very limited scope (only the code-block of the respective `if`).

Instead you'll want to create one variable with a bigger scope:

```
if (i == 0) { 
            final CharSequence[] items;
            if (j == 0) { 
                items = new CharSequence[] {"4:45", "5:00"};
            } else if (j == 1) { 
                items = new CharSequence[] {"4:43", "4:58"};
            } else if (j == 2) { 
                items = new CharSequence[] {"4:41", "4:56"};
            } else { 
                items = new CharSequence[] {"4:38", "4:53"};
            }
            // you can use items here
}
```

**Edit:** I forgot that the `new CharSequence[]` is necessary here. You can leave it out if you initialize the variable during declaration, but here you moved the declaration out and use a simple assignment to set a value. For some reason the short syntax of defining an array is *only* valid in an initializaton statement (i.e. in an assignment that is in the same statement as the declaration).

Comment: This is correct now, but see my answer for a much more concise alternative solution that works well in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you have strict block-level scope, so for example:

```
if (blah) { int foo = 1; }
// foo is no longer visible here
```

So once you reach that closing curly brace } your items variable is no longer visible. This is different from JavaScript for example where you have function-level scope.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, but what is the solution ?, how can I get a variable outside ? what do I need to create ?

Comment: You must declare the variable in the scope you intend to use it. `int foo = 0; if (blah) { foo = 1; } doSomethingWith(foo);`

Answer (score 1):

Because you *define* (as well as give a value to) `items` within a block, it is only visible within that block. Pull the definition out of the block to somewhere visible to both the snippets you have given us, and just *assign a value* within the `if` `else` construct.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `items` before the

```
if (i == 0) {
```

The way you are doing it now, `items` is only in scope inside you inner `if`s.

Comment: doesn't work for every situation, what if the type of the variable must be set inside the `if` ?

Comment: You can still define the variable outside of the if, then inside change/set the value

Answer (score 0):

You are only declaring items in local scope.  You need to move the

```
final CharSequence[] items
```

outside the if clauses and the instantiate it inside the if clause.

Comment: but what if the variable can have different types, that are set inside the `if` clause?