# Append to Jtextarea showing file location isntead of scanned contents

Tags: java, jtextarea, jfilechooser

This isn't the complete code, however I'm trying to append contents of a file into a JTextArea aslong as the have the specific case. my .txt file I'm opening contains

```
TEST
TEST
TEST
COLOR 100 100 100
```

The following results get posted to my console for debugging

```
Input Instruction Not Recognized1
Input Instruction Not Recognized2
Input Instruction Not Recognized3
```

and my JTextArea contains

```
C:\Users\c3462292\Documents\MuseLog.txt
```

however I am wanting it to display the only valid line which is COLOR 100 100 100, And also display the debugged line in order in the JTextAera but I can't seem to figure it out hope somebody can help.

```
         JMenuItem mntmOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
    mntmOpen.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Fucksakes.class.getResource("/Icons/Open.png")));
    mntmOpen.setFont(new Font("Roboto Condensed", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    mnFile.add(mntmOpen);
    mntmOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser broswer = new JFileChooser();
        int result = broswer.showOpenDialog(contentPane);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File selectFile = broswer.getSelectedFile();
        try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(selectFile);
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            lineNo++;
            process(sc.nextLine());
        }
        textArea.append(selectFile + "");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Cannot Open file");
        }
        }
        }
        });

public static void process(String s) {
    String[] a = s.split(" ");

    // Strings can be used in switch statements in Java 7 and later versions
    try {
        switch (a[0]) {
            case "COLOR":
                currentColor = new Color(Integer.parseInt(a[1]), Integer.parseInt(a[2]), Integer.parseInt(a[3]));
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Input Instruction Not Recognized");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only call `append(...)` on the JTextArea **once** in the code above, and it appends the text you're seeing, so that should not come as a complete surprise. No where are you even attempting to append any of the text in the file, so first thing I'd do if I were you would be to edit the code so that it does this.

Next, you're only testing the first String in your `a` array, and `a[0]` contains only TEST. So of course the switch block will go to the default line.

Comment: Is there any chance you can give me an example as I'm having quite a hard time understanding how should I be appending the different line to the JTextArea

Comment: @Savage: example of what? You've got too many issues with that code -- divide and conquer and try to solve one thing at a time.

Comment: Can you help me out with putting" the Input Instruction Not Recognized " into my jtextarea? I've been struggling with this all day.

Comment: @Savage: ? You already know how to append text to the JTextArea -- you're already doing this, just do the **same** thing. Call the append method as you're doing.

Comment: I'm unaware of which method I should be using, I've tried

Comment: I already told you, and you're already using it: the append method. How can you be using this method already in your code and not know which method to use? Search your code for that method and see for yourself.

Comment: I've tried textArea.append(s); but that isn't working I'm losing all hope

Comment: @Savage: But it is obviously what must be done. You don't show this attempt, and never tell us what problems you're having with it, and "isn't working" tells us nothing that can help us understand your problem. Please improve. Also, likely that method, `process(...)` should not be static. In fact none of your code should be static other than constants and the main method, and the main method should be very small and should only serve to get your GUI running and that's it.

Comment: I've changed my statics as suggested thanks for the input, However my          textArea.append(s); could not resolve it to a variable.

Comment: @Savage: then you may have a variable scope issue, but again, your question and code are still won't allow us to help you. Please go through the [tour] and do take a look at the [help] section as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section, so that your questions and answers will be better making your future experiences here better.

Comment: Also have a look at [Jon Skeet's StackOverflow Question Checklist](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). A shortened version of his [Writing the Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: @Savage: also look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585650/variable-cannot-be-resolved). Be sure that the textArea variable is declared on the class level and not in a method or constructor so that it's visible throughout the class.

Comment: I'm just struggling to grasp I need some visual guidance, the file location is getting appended to the JTextArea instead of the "COLOR 100 100" which is the valid line