# Scanner variable cannot be resolved

Tags: java

In my program, the user will be asked to input 3 integers. The integers will then be read using the `Scanner` class and listed back to the user.

This is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Echoer 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {

  /* The Data Below Will Read The Numbers Input Into The Prompt*/

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please Enter Three Integers: ");

  int number;
  number = input.nextInt();

  Scan.close();

  System.out.println("Thanks. The Numbers You Entered Are: " + number);

  } 
}
```

This is the error it returns:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Scan cannot be resolved
```

Why does it return this error? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: do `input.close()` instead of `Scan.close()`

Comment: You should not close a scanner tied to `System.in` at all. Closing something will always close the underlying resource, i.e. `System.in`. And you should only close what you opened yourself. However, `System.in` was opened by the JVM and the JVM will close it again. It's not your job to close it.

Comment: Your scanner variable is called `input`, not `Scan`. Java complaints about `Scan` not being a declared variable in your program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585650/variable-cannot-be-resolved).

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you never defined what `Scan` was. Use `input.close()` rather than `Scan.close()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Scan cannot be resolved

means that you never defined `Scan`. This is because you said `Scan.close()`. You need to change it to `input.close()` because `input` is the name of the instance of the `Scanner` class.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you have to close `input` instead of `Scan` as shown below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Echoer 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {

/* The Data Below Will Read The Numbers Input Into The Prompt*/

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please Enter Three Integers: ");

   int number;
   number = input.nextInt();

    input.close();

     System.out.println("Thanks. The Numbers You Entered Are: "+number);

}   
}
```